# AWS Athena JDBC driver and finding on in a maven repo?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, gradle, jdbc

I'm attempting to use the AWS Athena JDBC driver (AthenaJDBC42-2.0.2.jar)
[described here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html)

If I just take the jar and add it to classpath I have no problems.

When I move to a gradle build and add a dependency to a local version of the jar, again no problems.

```
compile files('libs/AthenaJDBC42_2.0.2.jar')
```

But what I really want to do is just fetch the jar from a repository somewhere only I can't seem to find this jar available in any repository.

Does anyone know if there is something special about this particular jar and why it isn't available in a repo?

Comment: There can be all kinds of reasons, most likely Simba didn't bother to release it to Maven central or another maven repository. As to the why, we don't know (opinion-based), and asking for off-site resources is also off-topic.

Comment: Thanks.  That is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one and it worked

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.syncron.amazonaws/simba-athena-jdbc-driver/2.0.2

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.syncron.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>simba-athena-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```